# How can I calculate Longitudinal Redundancy Check (LRC) in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code for LRC (PHP):

```
private function getLrc($string){
  $bytes = array_map(function($c) { return ord($c); }, str_split($string));     
  $byte = array_reduce($bytes, function($o, $i) { return $o ^= $i; });  
  return $byte;  //chr($byte);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow is not intended to be a transpilation service. You should learn Dart to be able to do this yourself in the future.

```dart
// include 'dart:convert';

int getLrc(string input) {
  final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
  final byte = bytes.reduce((o, i) => o ^= i);
  return byte;
}
```

Note that in Dart, strings are encoded with UTF-16 by default, so if the source string contains characters that are outside the UTF-8 format, this method will fail.